# Retrofit failing when trying to send GET request

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am getting the following error from Retrofit when trying to parse the API response:

```
[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 11 path $[0]]
```

The JSON is:

```
 [ 7407718726019,  18738122, 18732587, 18737891, 18729099, 18731581, 18737081, 18731938, 18731885, 187, 18724725, 18747879, 18732512, 18732217, 18746712 ]
```

There is no key for that list. Can anyone please help me with fixing this issue.

Here is my API definition interface:

```
public interface RemoteInterface {

    //Method for an api call
    @GET("v0/topstories.json?print=pretty")
    Call<List<Response>> getResponse();
}
```

This is how I am calling and processing the API:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Response> responses;
    RemoteInterface remoteInterface;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        remoteInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(RemoteInterface.class);
        Call<List<Response>> newsCall = remoteInterface.getResponse();


        newsCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Response>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Response>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<Response>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CharSequence) response.body
                        (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("response",response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Response>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("response",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you are expecting a list of `Response` object but the actual response is a list of Integers. use `List<Integer>` instead of `List<Response>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is a list of integers, and your Retrofit return is defined as `List<Response>`. The `Response` class is a Retrofit class describing a whole API response. It should not be used inside your definition like this.

Gson is expecting an object, but instead finds an integer and cannot parse that. To parse that, you should declare your expected return type as `List.

This is what the error message is telling you - it is looking for an object because that is what you have defined, but it finds a number because that is what the JSON contains.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to retrieve wrong data type, the json data you posted is an array of numbers, and you are trying to retrieve a list of response object. Instead try to retrieve

```
Call<List<Integer>> getResponse();
```

and if you get the error that says something like

> Can't parse primitive type

or something in those lines, you can try use **Scalars Converter factory**
with retrofit.
Thanks